# Check Column A if have value then check column B to have value. if Column B no value then run specific macro

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to vba and google through for some sample coding as mention in my title but couldn't find any related coding.

My intention is to run macro to check Column A if have value then check column B to have value. if Column B no value then run specific macro to grab the data from other workbook. I already have the macro to grab data from other workbook, just missing the 1st part of checking the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim LastRowA As Long, i As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRowA

            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" And .Range("B" & i).Value = "" Then
                'Run macro
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It work exactly what i wanted!!!